# getting "twentyzero" "thirty zero" printout

Tags: java

I am trying to printout words from original number. But I was struggline when I tried to enter 20, 30, 40, etc. However, the output would be "twentyzero" instead of "twenty". I made an empty string for zeros

```
String [] zero = {""};
```

And then made an If-statement when number = 0;

```
if (number == 0){ 
    String result = zero[number];
    System.out.print("");
    number = In.nextInt();
}
```

However, this didn't work at all. Does anyone have any idea about this. Thank you!

My full code:

```
public class NumberToWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        int number = In.nextInt();
        int onesDigit;
        int tensDigit;
        String[] zero = {""};
        String[] ones = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
                "eleven", "tweleve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};

        String[] tens = {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

        String[] hundreds = {"one hundred", "two hundred", "three hundred", "four hundred", "five hundred",
                "six hundred", "seven hundred", "eight hundred", "nine hundred"};
        while (number != -1) {
            if (number == 0) {
                String result = zero[number];
                System.out.print("");
                number = In.nextInt();

            }
            if (number < 20) {

                String result = ones[number];
                System.out.println("" + result);
                System.out.print("Number: ");
                number = In.nextInt();
            }
            if (number >= 20 && number <= 100) {

                tensDigit = number / 10;
                onesDigit = number % 10;
                System.out.println("" + tens[tensDigit] + "" + ones[onesDigit]);
                System.out.print("Number: ");
                number = In.nextInt();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's far too little information for us to be able to help you...

Comment: Sorry. I will give you my full code. Please have a look

Comment: The interesting part is the one you use to convert your number to a string. The part you didn't add to your post...

Comment: Sorry. Please have a look at my code that have been given. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be simply fixed by checking if `number` is divisible by 10 for any `number` where `20 <= number <= 100`.

```
if (number >= 20 && number <= 100) {

    tensDigit = number / 10;
    onesDigit = number % 10;
    if (onesDigit == 0) {
        System.out.println("" + tens[tensDigit])
    } else {
        System.out.println("" + tens[tensDigit] + "" + ones[onesDigit]);
    }
    System.out.print("Number: ");
    number = In.nextInt();

}
```